# When queryset returned more than one, how choice specific object?

Tags: django

I try get attribute value item from specific object with `queryset` below:

`x_img = ProductImages.objects.get(product_id=x_id)`, with that, return `more than one`, if i use `filter`, `x_img = ProductImages.objects.filter(product_id=x_id)`, the attribute i need(`image_file_w200_png`) is unvailable.

The context:

I want to create a dynamic values in my `head`, to do that my choice is `custom context_processors`, so:

head_meta_processors.py

```
import os
from .models import Product, ProductImages
def meta(request):
    path_id = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(request.path))
    x_id = path_id
    x_obj = Product.objects.get(pk=x_id)
    #...
    # here is the problem
    x_img = ProductImages.objects.get(product_id=x_id)
    x_meta_itemprop_image = x_img.image_file_w200_png.url
    
    return {
        #...
        'meta_itemprop_image': x_meta_itemprop_image,
        #...}
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    #... some fields

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    #... Fk to model above
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = ...
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=33,default='normal')    
    image_file_w200_png = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_to_image_file_w200_png,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default='default_image_thumbnail.png'
    )
```

Each `Product` model, can have many `ProductImages` related by `product_id` field.

So, my `queryset`, `ProductImages.objects.get(product_id=x_id)`, return 3 objects related with that `product_id`, how can access each one and how choice a specifc, like a index, e.g.:`x_img[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter(…)` and then subscript:

```
x_img = ProductImages.objects.filter(product_id=x_id)[0]
```

You can not subscript on a `.get(…)` since that raises an error when multiple items are returned, hence there is no result to subscript, but a `.filter(…)` returns a `QuerySet` that you can subscript.

The above will raise an error in case there is no record to return. You can use [**`.first()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) to return `None` instead:

```
x_img = ProductImages.objects.filter(product_id=x_id).first()
```